# C2DM show notification in notification area like gmail

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have experimented with c2dm and it works adn I am getting message ( I print simple toast ). How to set notification to look the same like notification for gmail for example, to show me in notification area, upper right corner when I get new ? Is there any flag for this or api ? ( At the momemnt I get message in code, extract from intent by key and show toast but there is nothing in notification area ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your C2DMReceiver Class which is extended from C2DMBaseReceiver. Put the following code under the override function onMessage, and also write a function named createNotification() which is given below.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {      
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String msg = extras.getString("data.c2dmsg");
        String msgTitle = extras.getString("data.c2dmsgtitle");
        String msgTicker = extras.getString("data.c2dmsgticker");
        createNotification(msgTitle, msg, msgTicker);
    }
}


 public void createNotification(String title, String messageText, String tickerttext) {
      int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_msg; // icon from resources
      CharSequence tickerText = tickerttext; // ticker-text
      long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); // notification time
      Context context = getApplicationContext(); // application Context
      CharSequence contentTitle = title; // expanded message title
      CharSequence contentText = messageText; // expanded message text
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomekhawarActivity.class);

      Bundle xtra = new Bundle();
      xtra.putString("title", title);
      xtra.putString("message", messageText);

      notificationIntent.putExtras(xtra);
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
          + PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

      NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
      Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
      notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,   contentIntent);
      notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
      notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
      notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
      notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
        | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
      final int HELLO_ID = rand.nextInt();
      mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
    }
```